# Dim declaration with assignment and Option Strict

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, compiler-errors, option-strict, option-explicit

I have run into an issue with my code, as follows:

```
Option Explicit Off

Option Strict On 'Results in Compiler Error. Expected base or compare or explicit or private

Sub DoSomething()

     Dim intOne As Integer 'This line works

     intOne = 1 'This line works

     Dim intTwo as Integer = 2 'Results in Compiler Error: Expected end of statement

End Sub
```

My issues are written as comments in the code above.

Even with a completely empty module, I am unable to enable the `Option Strict` option.

I think the solution is somewhere in Visual Studio's options.

Note: I have manually translated the error messages from German, so please expect a difference between the above and the official English versions.

Answer (score 3):

`Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` **must** be set at the very top, followed by any `Imports` followed by the class itself followed by the methods:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Net

Public Class Class1

    Private Sub DoSomething()
         Dim intOne As Integer
         intOne = 1

         Dim intTwo as Integer = 2 
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is the same for modules:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Net

Module Module1

    Public Sub DoSomething()

        Dim intOne As Integer
        intOne = 1

        Dim intTwo As Integer = 2
    End Sub

End Module
```

If you want to turn these options on or off for the entire project you can do so in the project properties:

[image]

Note that the settings in individual files (if any) will take precedence over the default settings set within the project properties.

Have a look at the documentation for more information on setting [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) and [Option  Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).